# Detecting CTRL+Wheel with CHtmlView

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control, zooming, mousewheel

I know how to set the zoom factor for a `CHtmlView`:

```
HRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::SetZoomFactor(long iZoom, bool bRefreshBrowser /*true*/)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    VARIANT vZoom;

    m_lZoomFactor = iZoom;

    if (bRefreshBrowser)
    {
        vZoom.vt = VT_I4;
        vZoom.lVal = iZoom;

        hr = ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, &vZoom, nullptr);
    }

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView::ExecWB(OLECMDID cmdID, OLECMDEXECOPT cmdexecopt, VARIANT *pvaIn, VARIANT *pvaOut)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    ASSERT(m_pBrowserApp != NULL);

    hr = m_pBrowserApp->ExecWB(cmdID, cmdexecopt, pvaIn, pvaOut);
    return hr;
}
```

I have just introduced a `CStatusBar` into the main editor that encompasses this view and one of my users has stated that they use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel</kbd> to change the zoom factor.

I have my menu structure with associated hotkeys that the user can use to change the zoom, thus my status bar pane is updated to the right value they selected.

But when they use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel</kbd> to change the zoom my application is not detecting this. So they zoom in or out to a scale and my status bar pane is staying at the original zoom factor.

With MFC and the `CHtmlView` web browser control how to I detect when they have changed the zoom using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel</kbd> so I can update my status pane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is `CHtmlView` with Doc/View structure, use `PreTranslateMessage` to catch messages.

Documentation for [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-mousewheel) suggests several macros for finding the state of virtual keys and wheel movement:

```
BOOL CMyHtmlView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pmsg)
{
    if(pmsg->message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        int fwKeys = GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(pmsg->wParam);
        int zDelta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(pmsg->wParam);
        if (fwKeys & MK_CONTROL)
        {
            //mousewheel + control key is down
            TRACE("%d %d\n", zDelta, zDelta / WHEEL_DELTA);

            //update statusbar, or return TRUE to handle this manually
        }
    }
    return CHtmlView::PreTranslateMessage(pmsg);
}
```

`CHtmlView` also has its own `CHtmlView::ExecWB` method to set and get the zoom value etc.

`CHtmlView::OnUpdateUI` should also send notification for the change.

---

But the browser may not send a signal at the right time. Just make a timer to wait 1 second after detecting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>WHEEL</kbd>. Example:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyHtmlView, CHtmlView)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

const int ID_TIMER_ZOOM = 1;

BOOL CMyHtmlView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pmsg)
{
    if(pmsg->message == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        if (GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(pmsg->wParam) & MK_CONTROL)
            SetTimer(ID_TIMER_ZOOM, 1000, NULL); //start timer for detecting zoom
    return CHtmlView::PreTranslateMessage(pmsg);
}

void CMyHtmlView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR timer_id)
{
    if(timer_id == ID_TIMER_ZOOM)
    {
        //get the zoom value
        VARIANT vZoom;
        vZoom.vt = VT_I4;
        vZoom.lVal = 0;
        ExecWB(OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, nullptr, &vZoom);
        TRACE("zoom %d\n", vZoom.lVal);

        //kill the timer
        KillTimer(timer_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But I need to work with it after it has been processed so I can get the new zoom factor value.

Comment: Tge above it detecting the mouse wheel before we process it. So the zoom factor hasn’t changed yet.

Comment: I already use the ExecWB method to get / set the zoom. But if the user does it via the mouse wheel I need to detect what the new value is after they have zoomed.

Comment: It takes time for the browser to process the message. Handle the message manually, or use `SetTimer/KillTimer` routine to create a 1 second delay before reading the zoom. `CHtmlView::OnUpdateUI` should receive a notification as well, though it too could be out of sync, depending on what your code is.

Comment: Ok. I am using CDialog and not the doc/view architecture. I will try timer. I was just hope to update and point of change.

Comment: Ah, are you suggesting I don’t run the base class and perform my own ExecWB call based on the zDelta values?

Comment: See the edit to make a wait function, it's probably the simplest way.

Comment: I see. I take it that in theory I could post a custom message from this triggered time event for the parent dialog to intercept.

Comment: There are more shortcuts to control zoom: `Ctrl`+`Plus`, `Ctrl`+`Minus`, `Ctrl`+`0` (at least which I know of)

Comment: I assume your `CChristianLifeMinistryHtmlView` is derived from `CHtmlView`, I just wrote it as `CMyHtmlView`, try copy/pasting that code.

Comment: Just to let you know that I added a registered message to my parent dialog. Then I got the web browser view to post this message with the new zoom value from that timer event. It works very well. :)

Comment: @zett42 I have all the shortcuts supported. My dialog menu reproduced the standard zoom features and hotkeys. They are all functional as well as a popup custom window.

Comment: Yes, it is derived from `CHtmlView`.